# Add style to moderator-only tags here on Meta.

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

Currently there is no style differentiation between regular tags and moderator-only tags here on Meta.  Could a different style be added for moderator-tag so that these can be easily seen at a glance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix is on the way.